# creating list in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I have a custom content type,  I going to create a list of my content type

 I found & read the great orchard guide for creating list of content type  in this link: 
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-lists


1. Now, instead of using admin dashboard for creating lists, how can I handle this work(create a list of my content type) using code? 


2. how do I do if I going to don't show my content type in dashboard panel for creating new item of my content type, and replace of it , show the link of "Create new list of my content type"?

thanks a lot

Comment: "Create a list using code", do you mean in a widget? in a controller? in a part? Please reformulate your second question

Comment: @devqon: thanks, I solved it! my question was wrong!